# Rails 3 Wicked PDF - include Paperclip S3 pdf files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, wicked-pdf

I have a Rails 3 app that uses these gems:

```
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem 'combine_pdf'
```

I'm using `wicked_pdf` to open a pdf for a `costproject`.  The `costproject` has an HTML page called `viewproject.pdf.erb`.

I'm trying to combine the wicked pdf with the costproject attachments into a single pdf.

This is my controller code:

```
  def viewproject
    @costproject = Costproject.find(params[:costproject_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        pdf = CombinePDF.new
        pdf2 = render_to_string pdf: "Costproject.pdf", template: "costprojects/viewproject", encoding: "UTF-8"
        pdf << CombinePDF.new(pdf2)
        @costproject.attachments.each do |attachment|
          pdf << CombinePDF.new(attachment.attach.path)
        end
        send_data pdf.to_pdf, :disposition => 'inline', :type => "application/pdf"
      end
    end
  end
```

The line `pdf << CombinePDF.new(pdf2)` is giving me:

```
string contains null byte
```

If I look at pdf2, it starts like this - so it looks like a pdf:

```
>> pdf2
=> "%PDF-1.4\n1 0 obj\n<<\n/Title (\xFE\xFF)\n/Producer (wkhtmltopdf)\n/CreationDate (D:20150405202628)\n>>\nendobj\n4 0 obj\n<<\n/Type /ExtGState\n/SA true\n/SM 0.02\n/ca 1.0\n/CA 1.0\n/AIS false\n/SMask /None>>\nendobj\n5 0 obj\n[/Pattern /DeviceRGB]\nendobj\n8 0 obj\n<<\n/Type /XObject\n/Subtype /Image\n/Width 71\n/Height 75\n/BitsPerComponent 8\n/ColorSpace /DeviceRGB\n/Length 9 0 R\n/Filter
```

I also tried `pdf << CombinePDF.new(pdf2.to_pdf)`

Thanks for the help!

UPDATE1

As a test, to see if pdf2 is working, I did this successfully:

```
  def viewproject
    @costproject = Costproject.find(params[:costproject_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        pdf2 = render_to_string pdf: "Costproject.pdf", template: "costprojects/viewproject", encoding: "UTF-8"

        send_data pdf2, :disposition => 'inline', :type => "application/pdf"
      end
    end
  end
```

UPDATE2

Myst was correct about using `parse`. Thanks!

I am now using this line in the controller code:

```
pdf << CombinePDF.new(attachment.attach.url)
```

I get this error:

```
No such file or directory - http://s3.amazonaws.com/ ...
```

But, if I copy the http address and paste into the browser the pdf shows up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am editing this answer to reflect the issue of remotely stored PDF files.

I should point out that without a persistent connection to the S3 storage and without using the S3 API, the following solution WILL effect performance*.

As I pointed out, the CombinePDF.new method is the same as the CombinePDF.load method. It accepts a file name and attempts to open the file. The CombinePDF.parse method will accept raw PDF data and parses it into a PDF Object.

In the following code I use `Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse(url))` to get the raw PDF data.

I recommend replacing this solution with a S3 native solution, so that the whole application can share one or more persistent connections. This is a performance issue that may or may not be important for you.

```
  require 'net/http'

  def viewproject
    @costproject = Costproject.find(params[:costproject_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        pdf = CombinePDF.new
        pdf2 = render_to_string pdf: "Costproject.pdf", template: "costprojects/viewproject", encoding: "UTF-8"
        pdf << CombinePDF.parse(pdf2)
        @costproject.attachments.each do |attachment|
          pdf << CombinePDF.parse( Net::HTTP.get( URI.parse( attachment.attach.url ) ) )
        end
        send_data pdf.to_pdf, :disposition => 'inline', :type => "application/pdf"
      end
    end
  end
```

* The performance hit is dependent on the amount of PDF attachments you have, on the number of users your app has, on network traffic, on your framework (single/multi-thread) and other factors.

A persistent connection should reduce the performance hit in a dramatic way, mainly due to the fact that establishing connections is an expensive action.

Comment: You're correct about using the `parse`.  But, now I have an issue that it works locally - because I save the attachment PDFs in Rails, but on Heroku, I use S3. I'm trying different code for `pdf << CombinePDF.new(attachment.attach.path)'

Comment: How would you normally access the raw file content from the S3 layer? Is it locally mounted? Do you use a specific API?

Comment: did you try `pdf << CombinePDF.new(attachment.attach.path)` ?

Comment: `attachemnt.attach.path` will work if the pdfs are stored in Rails.  It doesn't work when they are stored in S3.